# Inject, via type hinting, service provider into a middleware

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection

I'm trying to inject an instance of a service provider in a middleware like so:

```
class ApiMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  ApiManager $manager
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, ApiManager $manager)
    {
    // more code goes here
```

Whenever I try to access any route that leads to the API, I get the following error

```
Argument 3 passed to App\Http\Middleware\ApiMiddleware::handle() must be an instance of App\Http\Controllers\API\Helpers\ApiManager, none given
```

I'm absolutely sure I've registered the provider correctly as it works for Controllers.

A simple `dd(ManagerInstance)` in a route which doesn't have the middleware injected with the service provider instance gives me this:

```
ApiManager {#176}
```

So, it works.

My service provider looks like this:

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use App\Http\Controllers\API\Helpers\ApiManager;

class ApiServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton('App\Http\Controllers\API\Helpers\ApiManager', function($app)
        {
            return new ApiManager($app['config']['manager']);
        });
    }
}
```

It is registered in the `'providers'` array.

My questions are:

- Is it possible to inject into the middleware?(I suspect that's the actual problem, not something I've done).
- If not, what would be a good work-around for this?

  - At the moment I'm using something like this as a work-around - `$manager = app()->make('App\Http\Controllers\API\Helpers\ApiManager');`

---

Current middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class ApiMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $manager = app()->make('App\Http\Controllers\API\Helpers\ApiManager');

        return ! $manager->verifykey($request->get('key'))
            ? $manager->returnResponse(null, ['message' => KEY_INVALID, 'http_status' => 401], 401)
            : $next($request);
    }
}
```

---

What I'd want it to look like:

```
class ApiMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, ApiManager $manager)
    {
        return ! $manager->verifykey($request->get('key'))
            ? $manager->returnResponse(null, ['message' => KEY_INVALID, 'http_status' => 401], 401)
            : $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can inject everything in middleware's contructor.

Comment: @MaximLanin Well I must be doing something wrong then. Any pointers? Do you need me to post more code?

Comment: Yes, show please the whole middleware

Comment: I've posted the version of the current middleware(first one) and how I'd want it to end up version(second one).

Comment: Formatted as an answer. Take a look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update your middleware like this:

```
class ApiMiddleware
{
    /**
     * The ApiManager implementation.
     *
     * @var ApiManager
     */
    protected $manager;

    /**
     * Create a new middleware instance.
     *
     * @param  ApiManager  $auth
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(ApiManager $manager)
    {
        $this->manager = $manager;
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return ! $this->manager->verifykey($request->get('key'))
            ? $this->manager->returnResponse(null, ['message' => KEY_INVALID, 'http_status' => 401], 401)
            : $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, works like a charm. I'd upvote you twice if I could. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @Andrew you are welcome! ) For the future: if a class instantiated via Laravel's DI level (practically everything, by the way), you are able to inject anything in it via it's contructor. It works everywhere.

Comment: Thanks, that's really good to know for future use. I was expecting it to work via direct injection in the class method itself. The whole only construct thing was supposedly fixed in 5.1. Oh well, I'm still happy.